# Facebook auto posts on page tab

Tags: facebook, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

Im running a mvc2 application in a page tab on facebook.

The landing page contains a form, problem is, the validation for the form is executed on page load, this does not happen when debugging locally. Edit: Or when browsing the app directly not though the tab context.

Anyone knows if facebook auto-posts to the page for some reason?

//Twd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook is always using `POST` method for application canvas.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/477/

Comment: How would you solve my problem? It must be common to have a form on landing page? Edit: Ive actualy had a form before (couple months ago) without this issue so dont understand whats happened.

Comment: Generally I checking for names and values submitted from form, don't rely on just submission of POST request.

Comment: Well dont know how that would work as someone probably will click "submit" without any values entered and then the validation-error should be triggered. So cant check for no values entered. And also its a page tab not a canvas app...

Comment: You can easily check hidden elements values or even values of inputs with type submit and button